# Getting the second thread to add a number to the variable it takes in

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a program that asks the user for input (a number`= n`). A thread is then created to calculate the sum from 1 to `n`. I now want to create additional threads to add a number to the user input number `n`. The second thread then calculates the sum of 1 to `n+1`, and then the third thread will calculate the sum of 1 to `n+2`, for example.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <pthread.h>

void * thread_calc(void *);
int TotalSum=0;

int main()
{
    int iNumber;
    pthread_t tid, tid2;
    printf("Enter Number Up to Which You want to Sum :");
    scanf("%d",&iNumber);    
    pthread_create(&tid,NULL,thread_calc,(void *) &iNumber);
    //pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,thread_calc,(void *)(&iNumber+1));

    pthread_join(tid,NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2,NULL);


    printf("Thread %d running, Final Sum is : %d \n", tid,TotalSum);

    pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,thread_calc,(void *) &iNumber+1);
    pthread_join(tid,NULL);
    printf("Thread %d running, Final Sum is : %d \n", tid2,TotalSum);


    //    return 0;
}

void *thread_calc(void *num)
{
    int *iNumber;
    iNumber=(int*)num;

    TotalSum = ((*iNumber + 1)* (*iNumber))/2;

    pthread_exit(NULL);    
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem/difficulty are facing?